# Return from ArrayList only values that are smaller than X

Tags: java, arraylist

How can I write a method that compares values of passed `ArrayList` with passed int X and return `ArrayList` with values that are smaller than X.
If X is 4, and `ArrayList` is `[1,2,3,4,5]`, it would return `[1,2,3]`.

What I have so far:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        if (list.get(i) > x)
            list.remove(i);
    }return list;
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: it would be good if you can share some code. You can start with simple `if ( current_element_in_array < X)  add current_element_in_array to a new list`

Comment: that seems to be the simplest way to do it. Unless there are any requirements that the method needs to fulfill

Comment: Also, if you use a for loop to iterate and you are removing components of your list, you will throw off the indexing of the components in the list

Answer (score 1):

You can use streams.

```
performOperation(List<Integer> list, int x) {
   return list.stream().filter(l -> l < x).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and brutal way to do this without streams and iterator is something like this:

```
List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    if (list.get(i) < x){
        result.add((list.get(i));
    }
return result;
```